# jq - Return all top-level attribute keys which have a subattribute that matches a condition

Tags: jq

My JSON looks like:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "restricted": true
  },
  "bar": {
    "restricted": false
  },
  "baz": { }
}
```

As single line:

```
{"foo":{"restricted":true},"bar":{"restricted":false},"baz":{}}
```

I want to get all top-level attribute keys returned which are either `restricted == false` or don't have the `restricted` subattribute. With above example JSON, the expected output is:

```
"bar"
"baz"
```

Answer (score 8):

I came up with the following expression:

`jq "to_entries[] | select(.value.restricted|not) | .key"`

`to_entries` converts the top-level object to an array of objects with a `"key"` and a `"value"` attribute each:

```
[
  {
    "key": "foo135",
    "value": {
      "restricted": true
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "foo246",
    "value": {
      "restricted": false
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "foo345",
    "value": {}
  }
]
```

`[]` explodes this array. This is done in order to filter individual objects in the next step:

```
{
  "key": "foo135",
  "value": {
    "restricted": true
  }
}
{
  "key": "foo246",
  "value": {
    "restricted": false
  }
}
{
  "key": "foo345",
  "value": {}
}
```

Then a filter is applied for each object: `select(.value.restricted|not)`. To filter out attributes with the subattribute `restricted` being truthy, `.value.restricted` can be inverted with `|not` to select objects with `restricted == false` as well as objects without this attribute using a single condition:

```
{
  "key": "foo246",
  "value": {
    "restricted": false
  }
}
{
  "key": "foo345",
  "value": {}
}
```

Finally, the `"key"` attribute is selected: `.key`. This returns the names of the matching objects (originally the top-level attribute keys):

```
"foo246"
"foo345"
```

Note that the pipe character `|` in `select(...) | .key` isn't strictly needed. The result is the same without.

If a string array is desired as result...

```
[
  "foo246",
  "foo345"
]
```

... then the following expression can be used:

```
jq "to_entries | map(select(.value.restricted|not).key)"
```

As you can see, `select()` can be used inside of `map()` to filter out individual elements, and it can even be combined with the attribute filter `.key`.

If you append `[]` at the end like `map(...)[]`, then the array gets exploded and the result is a list of strings again, like in the initial example, but using a slightly different approach.

Comment: If you want the results as string array, i.e. `["foo246","foo345"]`, then you can pipe the result to jq again with the slurp option `-s`: `jq "to_entries|.[]|select(.value.restricted|not)|.key" | jq -s`.

Comment: If you want the results as an array, it would be much better e.g. to use map() instead of exploding the array.

Comment: perhaps more idiomatic : `jq 'to_entries[] | select(.value.restricted|not)| .key'`

Comment: @peak It took me a while to figure out how to combine `map()` with my selection criterion, but this seems to work: `jq "to_entries | map(select(.value.restricted|not).key)"`. I didn't know you could put `select()` inside `map()` to filter individual elements without exploding the array and even combine that with an attribute filter (`map(select(...)) | [.[].key]` would also work but is way less elegant).

Comment: BTW: For a list of strings `jq "to_entries | map(select(.value.restricted|not).key)[]"` works as well. And the pipe character between `select()` and `.key` in `jq "to_entries[] | select(.value.restricted|not) | .key"` can actually be spared.

Comment: @CoDEmanX : Good stuff, why not update your A instead? ;-) . (In the future, you can leave a comment to you commentors "See my updates and thanks for the ideas!"). . Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Updated my answer as suggested. Thank you all!